# ASP.NET MVC search box: use modal popup or inline div or redirect to another page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, asp.net-mvc-2, modal-dialog

I have a view with a textbox and a search button, eg CustomerTextBox and CustomerSearchButton.

The list of customers is too long to display in a dropdown, and there has to be advanced search functions anyway.

What is the best practice in MVC to handle this case?  When the user clicks on the search button, should it:

A. Load another view into a modal popup (eg /customers/search)?

B. Have the search form in a hidden div that expands when the search button is clicked?

C. Redirect the user to a search page by means of RedirectTo("/customers/search")?

I've only been doing MVC for 3 days so thanks to those who answer my questions that might have quite obvious answers that I cant see yet. :)

Comment: You should split this into multiple questions.  Your asking for half a book here.

Comment: Fine whatever.  I'm more interested in the main question: what is the best approach - A, B or C.  Questions on how to implement can come later.

Comment: see this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541821/how-to-simplify-my-statefull-interlaced-modal-dialogs-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's really up to you, what would fit your site better? If you need some advanced searching capabilities, create a /customers/search and redirect to it. If its somewhat simple and quick, use a modal popup, or expand a hidden div with a search field or two when clicking the button.

Check this out:

[How to implement search features in ASP.NET MVC applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563308/how-to-implement-search-features-in-asp-net-mvc-applications)