# MVC 3 - Best method to create a search on my 'Views'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, search

I am wondering what the best way to create a site search is in MVC 3.  I would like to be able to somehow index all of my static .cshtml view text and have it be searchable.

I have searched around a bit and thought that IndexTank might be the way to go but it seems that it was recently acquired and no longer supported.

I am pretty new to MVC so the easiest route is what I am after here. :)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement search features in ASP.NET MVC applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563308/how-to-implement-search-features-in-asp-net-mvc-applications)

Comment: Yes, indextank is no longer supported from 10 April 2011, but you could continue using IndexTank API service from one of the providers. For instance from http://indexden.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your static content to Resource files and then do the search on the resource files using something like [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

here is an example of someone using it http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bob, I checked Lucene, but I think it may be a bit over my head -- especially since the documentation on their site isn't working. :/

Comment: you could start with something as simple as a string contains, the concept is the same Lucene just gives you a lot more features for searching. I also added a link to some examples.

Comment: OK nice link.  Does it change your answer at all if I tell you I am not using a DB for anything - just about 200-300 'static' pages.

Comment: Lucene uses it's own document based indexing so you don't need SQL to use it

Comment: Do you have any examples of directory/file searching - as opposed to db/fake-data that I see in all the examples?  I just have 1 directory that will contain all the subfolders and content.

Comment: I have still been experimenting with Lucene and I think it will work for my purposes. But everything I find online for examples is relating to either SQL data or fake/temp data.  Also I don't have a use for a console app.   What I am after is to have my FLAT static cshtml pages indexed and searchable.  Does anyone have any suggestions or links on examples of this path to searching?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to embed a Google search box in your website that only searches your domain.

```
<!-- SiteSearch Google -->
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
  <label for="q">Search:</label>
  <input id="q" name="q" size="20" maxlength="255" value="" type="text"/>
  <input name="domains" value="http://www.mydomain.com/" type="hidden"/>
  <input name="sitesearch" value="http://www.mydomain.com/" checked="checked" id="mysite" type="radio"/>
  <label for="mysite">Just this site</label>
  <input name="sitesearch" value="" id="www" type="radio"/>
  <label for="www">WWW</label>
  <input name="btnG" value="Go" type="submit"/>
</form>
<!-- SiteSearch Google -->
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, as well as the Bing Web Helpers that VS2011 can install with NuGet -- however I can't have the branding on our site. Any other solutions similar to that without the logo?